# Whenever I use pytesseract.image_to_string it results in an error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ocr, python-tesseract

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('ocrtest.jpg')   
img = cv2.resize(img, (600,400))
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
cv2.imshow('Result', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Whenever I add line 5 -  the print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img)) line - , it results in this giant error saying file not found error, and at the very bottom it says tesseract not found. I am using Anaconda Jupyter notebook, and pytesseract is downloaded in the Anaconda file, not the Jupyter notebook file on my desktop. Could that be the problem? If that line is not added, the code runs correctly and opens up the image file. The jpg image is downloaded within the desktop folder.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The ndarray from opencv is not support for pytesseract text extraction. Make use of **pillow** instead of **opencv-python**.

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("ocrtest.jpg")
resized_img = img.resize((600,400))
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(resized_img))
img.show()
```

Hope this will help you.